# Choosing input method when on MessagEase

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, messagease-keyboard

Recently found the [MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb) keyboard and really like it, but don't necessarily want to use it all the time.

With the other keyboards I use, I long press on the spacebar will open the "Choose input method" selection, but not so with MessagEase.

[Their FAQ](https://www.exideas.com/ME/android_faq.html) says to "Tap and hold on any text field" to switch input methods, but that doesn't seem to work for me (just get the standard cut, copy, paste, etc pop-up).

Currently have to go into the Android settings under Manage Keyboards and disable MessagEase to switch to a different keyboard, which is sub-optimal.

Any ideas of an easier way?

(Android 10/LineageOS 17.1)

Comment: If you're inside an input field, check the notification bar/area. It then usually carries a "keyboard icon". The corresponding entry in the notification area should offer you available IMEs to switch to then.

Comment: @Izzy An older version of Android had this, but my current version doesn't seem to. (Android 10/LineageOS 17.1) Thanks.

Comment: @Evan I have the same combination myself (LineageOS 17.1+MessagEase 13.01) and the keyboard icon appears, but only after you've been to Settings | System | Languages & Input | Virtual keyboard, and enabled _both_ MessagEase and the Android keyboard. (I use it to select newer emojis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2024, given that MessagEase wants to introduce a subscription model, your best option seems to be to install Thumb-Key instead. It's open source and doesn't nag you. With Thumb-Key you switch to a different input method by swiping down on the Smiley.